# Find files older than a given file minus a few hours

Tags: find, ksh

I'm using the following to find all files that are older than a reference file...

```
find /home/testuser -name "dummyfiles*" ! -newer referencefile.txt
```

... which works as expected.

However, I want to add a bit of leniency to the time, so that it only finds files that are older than the reference file - a few hours.

For example, if I have a reference file with modification date `May 26 11:26`, I want to find files that are older than `May 26 9:26` (ie, with a 2-hour leniency on the reference file).

In this example, the following would be correct matches...

```
May 26 7:00
Apr 15 14:00
```

... and the following should **not** match...

```
Jun 13 9:00
May 26 10:00
```

Ultimately I want to delete all the files that I find, so would love it if `find` was able to handle this requirement? Otherwise, are there any other alternatives that will allow me to delete these files without being too convoluted?

Comment: Please, can you clarify if you are looking for 1) files older than the reference file 2hour OR more than 2hour (>=) 2) files that are older that the reference file exactly 2 hour. (=)

Comment: I'm looking for files that are older that the reference file less 2 hours. See the example in my question - in the example, I would want all files that are older than `May 26 9:26`, so it should also match files with dates `May 26 7:00`, `Apr 15 14:50`, ... but not match dates `Jun 13 9:00` or `May 26 10:00`.

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system, you could do something like:

```
TZ=UTC0 find /home/testuser -name "dummyfiles*" ! -newermt "$(
  TZ=XXX2:00:00 date -r referencefile.txt +%FT%T.%N)"
```

That is, get `date` to print the modification of the file in a timezone 2 hours behind UTC (so if the file was last modified at 15:00 UTC, `date` will print `13:00`) and get `find` to interpret that timestamp as UTC time (so in our example, will try to find files last modified before 13:00 UTC).

That's limited to offsets of up to 24 hours (or 48 hours if you use `TZ=XXX-24` for `find`). For arbitrary offsets, you can do:

```
(
export TZ=UTC0
find /home/testuser -name "dummyfiles*" ! -newermt "$(
  date -d "$(date -r referencefile.txt +%FT%T.%N) - 2 hours" +%FT%T.%N)"
)
```

Or you could use `perl`:

```
perl -MFile::Find -le '
  $min_age = (-M "referencefile.txt") + 2/24;
  find (sub {
    print $File::Find::name if $_ =~ /^dummyfiles/ && (-M$_) > $min_age
    }, @ARGV)
  ' -- /home/testuser
```

Note that contrary to `find` (but like GNU `date -r`), for symlinks `perl`'s `-M` considers the age of the file it links to, not the age of the symlink itself. The subsecond part of the timestamp is also not considered.

Answer (score -2):

Try out with this :

```
find /home/testuser -name "dummyfiles*" ! -newer referencefile.txt -mmin +120 -print
```

adding the parameter `-mmin +120` find command will return only the files older than 2-hour in comparison to referencefile.txt modification date.

#### test:

```
mkdir find
touch find/dummyfiles1 find/dummyfiles2 find/dummyfiles3 find/dummyfiles4 find/referencefile.txt
touch -t 8001031305 dummyfiles1 dummyfiles2
find find/ -name "dummyfiles*" ! -newer find/referencefile.txt -mmin +120
```

#### output:

> find/dummyfiles1
>
> find/dummyfiles2

Comment: You should explain why your solution is different to what the OP is already doing, and how it solves their problem.

Comment: Improved the answer, It was so late in my country : )

Comment: No, this doesn't do what you claim. This command matches files that are older than `referencefile.txt` and at least two hours old. Nothing here says “two hours older than the reference file”.

Comment: This answer do exaclty what I claim (don't call me storyteller) : "return only the files older than 2-hour"(it's what I'm claiming). Anyway, maybe I missed understood the question. Waiting for a clarification from the OP